# how to make a service that runs in background and send notifications in Android

Tags: android, networking, service, background, startup

The application that i am developing needs to run a service in startup, and collects information from remote servers every 5min.

When the user run the main application, he finds the notifications that the service has collected.

How can I run a service in startup and in background, and stay running even if the application is not used?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Started Service as explained here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Which is informing the Activity via an Bradcast:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html